# Off-canvas push footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build an off-canvas push footer.
 
The idea is that that when selecting different options from the footer menu, the rest of the page gets pushed up to show the footer content
There is a tutorial for a sliding footer menu [**here**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/) but since it slides the [footer] content on top (as in top-layer) of the page this is not what I am looking for.
By using the bootstrap "accordion" I have managed to have the content drop down below the page, but since this falls outside the field of view (browser window), I am afraid that some visitors will not find it.

Here is a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tomtom/e3ZLP/)

```
<div class="pushDown">Please scroll down to bottom</div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading col-xs-6">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </a>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading col-xs-6">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
      Collapsible Group Item #2
    </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    CONTENT 1
  </div>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    CONTENT 2
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to have the panels push up the rest of the content instead of dropping down?


Option 2 - here I have tweaked [Christopher Yee's plugin](http://christopheryee.ca/pushy/) to behave as I need but I can only get it to work with one button

[**PushFooter**](http://nr.x10.mx/pushFooter/)

```
$(function() {
var pushy = $('.pushy'), //menu css class
    body = $('body'),
    container = $('#container'), //container css class
    push = $('.push'), //css class to add pushy capability
    siteOverlay = $('.site-overlay'), //site overlay
    pushyClass = "pushy-left pushy-open", //menu position & menu open class
    pushyActiveClass = "pushy-active", //css class to toggle site overlay
    containerClass = "container-push", //container open class
    pushClass = "push-push", //css class to add pushy capability
    menuBtn = $('.menu-btn, .pushy a'), //css classes to toggle the menu
    menuSpeed = 300, //jQuery fallback menu speed
    menuWidth = pushy.width() + "px"; //jQuery fallback menu width

function togglePushy(){
    body.toggleClass(pushyActiveClass); //toggle site overlay
    pushy.toggleClass(pushyClass);
    container.toggleClass(containerClass);
    push.toggleClass(pushClass); //css class to add pushy capability
}
```

How would I edit the JS if I would use the class names `.pushy-left2` `.menu-btn2` `.pushy2` etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try to make an #id stick to the content area of the footer, and make a link in the trigger of the accordion.

when you click the link make it link to the content area 'a href="mysite.com/home#article"'

so it centers the page on that piece of information

Comment: you mean making a anchor link?

Comment: I already tried that, but since the "href" is already taken for the "toggle" function this won't work right? Could you update my 'fiddle' with a working example?

Comment: cant you make a link in the other link ? if that doesnt work i dont know any other ways im sorry :)